# Save Emacs window size on Windows XP

Tags: windows, emacs

Recently i bought laptop with Windows XP. I'd really like to start using emacs on it but there is one problem - when I start emacs it just do not fit vertically to my screen. So every time I launch emacs I should begin with resizing its window which is quite embarrassing and inconvenient.
Is there any way to automatically save at exit and restore at startup emacs window size?

**update** I moved my code to the question answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put in `.emacs` this piece of code

```
(defun restore-saved-window-size()
  (unless (load "~/.emacs.d/whsettings" t nil t)
    (setq saved-window-size '(80 30)))
  (nconc default-frame-alist `((width . ,(car saved-window-size))
                   (height . ,(cadr saved-window-size)))))

(restore-saved-window-size)

(defun save-window-size-if-changed (&optional unused)
  (let ((original-window-size  `(,(frame-width) ,(frame-height))))
    (unless (equal original-window-size saved-window-size)
      (with-temp-buffer
        (setq saved-window-size original-window-size) 
        (insert (concat "(setq saved-window-size '"
                        (prin1-to-string saved-window-size) ")"))
        (write-file "~/.emacs.d/whsettings")))))

(add-hook 'window-size-change-functions 'save-window-size-if-changed)
```

Works great on my Windows XP
For shortcut, can create file named `emacs.cmd` in `%system32%` folder with following content: `C:\`*`path-to-emacs`*`\bin\runemacs.exe  %*` to be able to launch it from cmd everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Save the following to a .reg file and import it into the registry:

```
REGEDIT4
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\GNU\Emacs]
"Emacs.Geometry"="80x32+100+0"
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my .emacs to fix the size

```
(defvar max-width  80)
(defvar max-height 50)
```

Comment: it is not it at all

Answer (score 0):

[John T](https://superuser.com/questions/100646/save-emacs-window-size-on-windows-xp/100615#100615) answered the question.

For further information about what Emacs reads in the Windows registry, check the [MsWindowsRegistry](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MsWindowsRegistry) page on EmacsWiki.

Comment: did you read my question?

Comment: "save and restore" No, I guess not. :-/

You should write your answer as an Answer so I can upvote it.

Comment: I finally got enough rep, so upvoting yours.